# How to fix stat.st_size sometime giving incorrect size of the file in c program?

Tags: c, system-calls, filesize, stat

I am trying to solve the question

Write a C program to display all the files from the current directory and its subdirectory
whose size is greater than ’n’ Bytes Where n is accepted from the user through command
line.

My code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<stdlib.h> //atoi() for conversion of  string to int
#include<string.h>

void print_file_names(char dir_name[100],long nByte);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dirent;
    struct stat st;
    long nByte;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of argument...!");
        return 0;
    }
    nByte = atoi(argv[1]);

    dir = opendir(".");
    while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if(dirent->d_type == 4) // folder or directory
        {  
            print_file_names(dirent->d_name,nByte);
        }else
        {
            stat(dirent->d_name,&st);
            if(st.st_size > nByte)
            {
                printf("Directory Name = Current  --  File Name = %s  --  Size = %ld\n",dirent->d_name,st.st_size);
            } 
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

void print_file_names(char dir_name[100],long nByte)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dirent;
    struct stat st;
    int size;
    
   

    
    if(strcmp(dir_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(dir_name,"..") == 0 || dir_name[0] == '.')
    {
        return;
    }

    
    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if(dirent->d_type == 8) //file
        {

            stat(dirent->d_name,&st);
            size = st.st_size;
            if(size > nByte)
            {
                printf("Directory Name = %s  --  File Name = %s  --  Size = %d\n",dir_name,dirent->d_name,size);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

The output of above code is as follows

```
Directory Name = Current  --  File Name = q2.c  --  Size = 870
Directory Name = Current  --  File Name = a.out  --  Size = 17112
Directory Name = adir  --  File Name = new.txt  --  Size = 43131868
Directory Name = adir  --  File Name = temp.txt  --  Size = 43
Directory Name = Current  --  File Name = newFile.txt  --  Size = 39
Directory Name = Current  --  File Name = q5.c  --  Size = 1592
```

Not all sizes are wrong but some are wrong.

Expected output is
**Directory Name = adir  --  File Name = new.txt  --  Size = 40**

for new.txt is containing only 30 - 40 characters but st.st_size returning to large number.

Comment: Could you tell us what you expect where you get a wrong number?

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Also, have you enabled all warnings? I would suggest using `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-Wformat=2`.

Comment: (Also, you should use constants like `DT_DIR` and `DT_REG` instead of magic numbers when checking the (non-standard) `d_type` field, and also account for cases where it's `DT_UNKNOWN`)

Comment: Sometimes for new.txt output is Directory Name = adir  --  File Name = new.txt  --  Size = 174853848. i think is garbage values.How can i fix it..?

Comment: Hint: Always check the return value of functions for success before trying to use what they return/set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stat outputting the wrong values for files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284709/stat-outputting-the-wrong-values-for-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: @Amol_G Yes, you are getting garbage values.  You need to check the return value from the `stat()` call.  If the return value is not 0, this means the call failed for some reason, and the data in `st` is meaningless.

Comment: It is likely that many of your `stat()` calls *are* failing, because you're giving them a path that does not exist, because you're not properly constructing pathnames in your recursive calls.

Comment: Yes there is path issue..!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<stdlib.h> //atoi() for conversion of  string to int
#include<string.h>

void print_file_names(char dir_name[100],long nByte);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dirent;
    struct stat st;
    long nByte;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of argument...!");
        return 0;
    }
    nByte = atoi(argv[1]);

    dir = opendir(".");
    while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if(dirent->d_type == DT_DIR) // folder or directory
        {  
            print_file_names(dirent->d_name,nByte);
        }else
        {
            stat(dirent->d_name,&st);
            if(st.st_size > nByte)
            {
                printf("Directory Name = Current  --  File Name = %s  --  Size = %ld\n",dirent->d_name,st.st_size);
            } 
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

void print_file_names(char dir_name[100],long nByte)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dirent;
    struct stat st;
    int size;
    char path[100];
    
   

    
    if(strcmp(dir_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(dir_name,"..") == 0 || dir_name[0] == '.')
    {
        return;
    }

    
    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if(dirent->d_type == DT_REG) //regular file
        {
            path[0] = '\0';
            strcat(path,dir_name);
            strcat(path,"/");
            
            strcat(path,dirent->d_name);
            stat(path,&st);

            size = st.st_size;
            if(size > nByte)
            {
                printf("Directory Name = %s  --  File Name = %s  --  Size = %d\n",dir_name,dirent->d_name,size);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

**When file is in subfolder stat() new path as stat("subfolder/file.txt",&st);

So I create a path variable for every file in a subfolder.
and dirent->d_name give only file.txt**